# Can someone explain Why i need to use await in 2 different functions to fetch json?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Example:

```
    async function getInitialVideos(){
         const ans= await fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&videoEmbeddable=true&type=video&key=${APIKEY}&q=${'The Beatles'}`).then(res=>res.json())

    }

    async function onInit() {
        await getInitialVideos()
          DoSomething()
}
```

in this function i say wait for the promise to resolve and fetch me that json,
why would i need await in the second function?

i mean if i drop it the second functions starts executing before i get the values from the first.
lets say i want that fetch function to be a const that always gets that value,
how would i implement it and make sure it waits without waiting again in a different function?

Comment: This might be helpful https://jakearchibald.com/2017/await-vs-return-vs-return-await/

Comment: If `DoSomething()` needs `getInitialVideos()` to do its job first, and when `getInitialVideos()` needs the result of the `fetch()`, then you have to wait twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` doesn't make asynchronous code synchronous. It just gives the illusion that it is inside a function marked as `async`.

When the JS engine reaches `await` it will put the function to sleep until the promise you await resolves.

If you `await` `getInitialVideos` then `onInit` will go to sleep until the promise returned by `getInitialVideos` resolves (at which point it will wake up and carry on with `DoSomething`).

If you **don't** `await`  `getInitialVideos` then when `getInitialVideos` goes to sleep (because it is `await`ing `fetch().then()`) `onInit` will continue with `DoSomething`. Then at some point in the future, `fetch().then()` will resolve and `getInitialVideos` will wake up and continue.

Comment: btw, i managed to get it to work with  just returning the fetch without waiting for it in the getInitialVideos function, and waiting for it on the onInit, so 2 awaits were not really needed since 1 does the job